# How do I get detailed logs from the Roku?

Tags: roku

I currently testing an HLS stream on the simple video player template provided by the roku developer site.

If i'm testing a channel on the roku and my HLS stream is failing, how view and get detailed logs on why its failing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way I've found to troubleshoot any Roku application is to sideload your content via telnet and print statements out to your console. You can get detailed information from the [Roku developer docs](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-71EnablingDevelopmentModeonyourbox) about how to enable developer mode on the box, then you can simply telnet in, like so:

```
telnet [ip address] 8085
```

At that point, you will see anything you print out from your application. For instance, if you print messages from your video player:

```
while true
  msg = wait(0, port)

  if type(msg) = "roVideoScreenEvent" then
     if msg.isRequestFailed()
       print "Video request failure: "; msg.GetIndex(); " " msg.GetData()
     elseif msg.isStatusMessage()
       ...etc
     end if
  end if
end while
```

Alternately, you could set up Google Analytics and report that way if you can't gain access to a device having the problems.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet for determining why an HLS stream is failing is to listen for the [roVideoScreenEvent.isRequestFailed()](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roVideoPlayerEvent) event in your roVideoScreen event loop.  If that doesn't give you the information you need, you can add an [roSystemLog](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roSystemLog) and enable the "http.connect" and "http.error" events to see if the player is requesting the expected URLs for the stream and/or erroring when requesting those URLs.