# Pulling Bandwidth logs from Roku

Tags: logging, streaming, latency, roku

Due to the nature of my job, my customers often stream media over a high latency network. Usually see around 700ms - 1000ms. The situation is customers streaming video over a KA satellite network in a business jet.

They use a Roku with various streaming apps. Sometimes we encounter buffering, etc. These data plans they are on all have the same latency but different Mbps speeds.

Is there a way that I can monitor or pull logs directly from the Roku to monitor the bitrate being used while streaming? While doing this on the aircraft it is not possible for me to sit between the Roku and the router in order to use Wireshark, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this question help any? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202227/how-do-i-get-detailed-logs-from-the-roku

Answer (score 0):

This may be a long shot, but my advice is to have your company reach out to the Roku company directly and ask if it would be possible to create a custom analytics dashboard.

Information on their analytics dashboards can be found here: https://developer.roku.com/en-ca/docs/features/analytics/analytics-reports.md

The use case for their current analytics dashboards are for channel owners to see how their channel is doing in terms of crashes, buffering data, etc. Your use case is unique in that you care about the actual devices more than the specific channel data.

It seems as though there may be device specific data since there is an option to filter analytics by device type, but I don't know if that means they can filter analytics by individual devices.

What you would want is the Health information per device, not per channel. Again, this is an atypical use case, but it is possible that the good folks at Roku can help you. Then again, it may be impossible, but it can't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 0):

As I think, you need to develop a custom solution to collect the data. Below I am summarizing my approach, If I have to develop this solution--

**1.** First try to get unique box identifier, which we access using **'GetChannelClientId()'** or **'GetClientTrackingId()'** of **'roDeviceInfo'** component.

**2.** Get the required system log. For example- to access bandwidth(or other events), we can use **'roSystemLog'** component. We have to make sure that we are attaching system log events to the same **messageport** on which our media player is running.

**3.** Capture **'roSystemLogEvent'** and Use some **REST API** to send captured data to your server and store it some table schema in your database. Its same as we send data for analytics events.

**4.** Now we can access device specific data from the database and analyze it.

If you are thinking to develop this kind of solution or any other approach you are planning, it will be my pleasure to help you.